# How to store object with property of generic type in DB

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-10g

In my business domain there exists an entity *parameter*. Beside other properties which are identical for each *parameter*, they have *values*. These *values* can be of different data types. There might be *values* that are strings, integers, timestamps, IP-Adresses, etc. It is also possible that I need to add another data type later but this should happen not very frequently.
New *parameters* will be inserted frequently. *Values* of existing parameters will probably be updated several different times. *Parameters* and *values* will be read very frequently but only for displaying them to the user, so without any special analytical operation.

For the later code (which will be C++) I was thinking of a *parameter* base class from which subclasses for each data type will be derived. *StringParameter*, *TimestampParameter*, etc.

I was now wondering how to store *parameters* in an Oracle 10g database. Ideas so far are

- Single table, string column: A single database table for all *parameters* where the column type for the *value* is **VARCHAR2**. The code can then transform the *values* to the correct data type by using functions like **atoi**. Drawback is I would need an extra *type* column and transforming *values* back and forth with **atoi** and **itoa** is not very safe and neither good maintainable (e.g. if the data type of one parameter changes from **int** to **long**).
- Single table, raw column: A single database table for all *parameters* where the column type for the *value* is **RAW**. The code then just stores and retrieves the property "as-is" in binary. Drawback is I would need an extra *type* column and changing the data type of a *parameter* would break backward compatibility (or one would need to perform a database upgrade which converts all old *values* to the new ones.
- Multiple tables, one for each data type: A basic *parameter* table for all common properties and several extra tables only for the *value* so that the column can be of the correct data type. Drawback: Not all data types from my domain can be mapped to an oracle data type. Additionally I would need a lot of new tables and joins. Also introducing new parameters would need a change in the database schema.

For which option would you go and why? Is there another solution I have not yet thought of?

Comment: Answer depends on planned requirements for object processing: use database only for storage, perform some modification of objects in database, perform some analytic operations on stored objects etc. So, please update your question with description of processing goals.

Comment: Added a paragraph on the usage scenario. Hope that clarifies the scope of my question.